# Move all exchange pages from default web site to a sub domain IIS

Tags: windows, exchange

I have currently upgraded server and exchange to 2019. And now I would like to solve a problem which is follow me since years.
The web access of my home page (Typo3) get always in conflict whit the exchange pages. Instead to get a Typo3 responce the exchange/owa login page will displayed.

My idea is to move all exchange pages to the sub domain mail. So instead of access the exchange pages with [www.domain.com/...](http://www.domain.com/...). I have to call mail.domain.com/...

I hope that would solve the conflict between exchange and the home page and also not change the IIS configuration after update exchange with a new CU.

Would this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should not run other websites, or any other web content at all, on Exchange servers.

Exchange needs to have full control on IIS on the server where it's running, and it *will* overwrite any configuration change you manually make in IIS.

You *can* change the URLs for Exchange web services (including OWA), but you still *really* need to run everything that is not Exchange on a different web server.

Answer (score 0):

> The web access of my home page (Typo3) get always in conflict whit the exchange pages. Instead to get a Typo3 responce the exchange/owa login page will displayed.

Did you configure some redirect settings or rewrite rules for your home page? (**[Use IIS Manager to configure the default website to redirect to the /owa virtual directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/outlook-on-the-web/http-to-https-redirection?view=exchserver-2019#step-3-use-iis-manager-to-configure-the-default-website-to-redirect-to-the-owa-virtual-directory)**)

Check if they are existing, if so, try to disable and see if there is any difference.